# How to return all records but exclude the last item

Tags: django, django-models

I'm having problem filtering in `django-models`.

I want to return all records of a particular `animal` but excluding the last item based on the latest `created_at` value and sorted in a descending order.

I have this model.

```
class Heat(models.Model):

    # Fields
    performer = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    is_bred = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    result = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # Relationship Fields
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal, related_name='heats', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
```

I was able to achieved the desired result by this raw sql script. But I want a django approach.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    heat
WHERE
    heat.created_at != (SELECT MAX((heat.created_at)) FROM heat)
        AND heat.animal_id = '2' ORDER BY heat.created_at DESC;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For all objects:

```
Heat.objects.order_by("-created_at")[1:]
```

For a particular animal it will be:

```
Heat.objects.filter(animal_id=2).order_by("-created_at")[1:]
```

where `[1:]` on a [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/) has regular [python slice](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) syntax and translates to SQL `LIMIT` syntax. (In this example it simply removes the first  / most recently created element)

Upd: as @schwobaseggl mentioned in his comment, slices with negative indices don't work on django querysets. Therefore the objects are reverse ordered first.

Comment: @Art, thanks for your response but schwobaseggl was right even when i changed it to 1 still not a desired result.

Comment: @Art thanks! it works this solution is simple. and this is what exactly what i want a reverse ordered.

Comment: @Art Much better ;)

Answer (score 4):

I just converted your SQL query to Django ORM code.

First, fetch the max `created_at` value using [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) and do an [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude).

```
from django.db.models import Max

heat_objects = Heat.objects.filter(
    animal_id=2
).exclude(
    created_at=Heat.objects.all().aggregate(Max('created_at'))['created_at__max']
)
```

Comment: this one might be helpful in the future can you give some explanation?

Comment: Thank you this might be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Get last record:

```
obj= Heat.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0]
```

Make query:

```
query = Heat.objects.filter(animal_id=2).exclude(id=obj['id']).all()
```

Answer (score -1):

The query would be :

```
Heat.objects.all().order_by('id')[1:]
```

You could also put any filter you require by replacing all()